# Information and image of Genus Acesina

Tags: zoology, taxonomy

I am searching for image and information, like distribution etc of the genus Acesina. The Taxonomic tree is:

```
Kingdom:        Animalia
Phylum:         Arthropoda
Class:          Insecta
Order:          Lepidoptera
Superfamily:    Papilionoidea
Family:         Lycaenidae
Genus:          Acesina
```

According to [Catalogue of Life](http://www.catalogueoflife.org/col/browse/tree) this genus has the 4 species. I haven't found any information by searching web, even the species are extinct or not! Any pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: @kmm thank you for the information. Can you post your comment as the answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: Also described at  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acesina

Answer (score 1):

The genus *Acesina* has been revised and is now part of the genus *[Arhopala](http://tolweb.org/Arhopala/112304)*. The [wikipedia page for *Arhopala*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arhopala) has some additional information on this genus.